# Order by more than 1 field in INNER JOIN queries

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT products.id, 
       products.title, 
       products.size, 
       products.price, 
       products.text_description, 
       products.main_description, 
       products.priority, 
       gallery.id, 
       gallery.main 
       FROM gallery INNER JOIN products ON gallery.id=products.id 
       GROUP BY products.priority ASC
```

Each product in the database has several images associated with it. The query above lists the product with 1 image of that product. Each picture has a field with a timestamp which the entry gets when uploading the image. I need to modify the SQL query above to get, say, the first image which was uploaded for the certain product, something like `ORDER BY UPLOAD_TIME ASC`. Could anybody help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: There are several possible ways to this. But for performance reasons it would be a very good idea to tell the audience the database product and version you are using.

Comment: Considering the `GROUP BY` clause I'm Guessing MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two ways to actually control which row you get in MySQL when you want the first row for a group

**Using limit 1**

```
SELECT products.id, 
       products.title, 
       products.size, 
       products.price, 
       products.text_description, 
       products.main_description, 
       products.priority, 
       gallery.id, 
       gallery.main 
FROM products
CROSS JOIN 
 (SELECT   
       gallery.id, 
       gallery.main  
    FROM 
        gallery
    WHERE
        products.[id] = gallery.[id]
    ORDER BY 
        gallery.[timestamp] DESC
    LIMIT 1) gallery
GROUP BY 
    products.priority ASC
```

Now this works as well. 
**Using MAx()**

```
SELECT products.id, 
       products.title, 
       products.size, 
       products.price, 
       products.text_description, 
       products.main_description, 
       products.priority, 
       gallery.id, 
       gallery.main 
FROM products
INNER JOIN gallery 
ON products.id = gallery.id
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT   
       max(gallery.timestamp) timestamp, 
       gallery.[id]
    FROM 
        gallery
    GROUP BY
        gallery.[id]
    ) maxgallery
ON gallery.id = maxgallery.id and gallery.timestamp = maxgallery.timestamp
GROUP BY 
    products.priority ASC
```

Aside from potential differences in performance you must take special care on how these two queries handle ties

If there's two records that share id and timestamp using `LIMIT 1` will only return one record. When using `MAX()` more than one record can be returned.

I'll leave it to you on which one is preferable or if it makes a difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         col1,
         col2,...,
         coln 
    FROM 
        products 
    WHERE
        products.[id] = gallery.[id]
    ORDER BY
        products.[timestamp] DESC)
ON...
```

This will be a slower query, as it needs to do the nested subquery for each row in the main query... perhaps loading the relevant table data into an in-memory table will speed it up.